# How to make a background slideshow in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my website's background to change images every 5 seconds. For that I creare a jquery script. The problem is that the images are not full-height or full-width. One more thing is that I can not make the images fade out and in without the withe background being noticed. Can anyone help me?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function() {           
        var i =0; 
        var images = ['geral2.jpg','geral3.jpg','geral4.jpg','geral5.jpg','geral6.jpg'];
        var image = $('#slideit');
        image.css('background', 'url(geral1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed');
        setInterval(function(){         
            image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            image.css('background', 'url(' + images [i++] +') no-repeat center center fixed');
            image.fadeIn(1000);
            });
            if(i == images.length)
                i = 0;
        }, 5000);            
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="slideit" style="width:100%;height:100%; background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;">
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: It is full screen, but is looping the first image. How can I solve?

http://codepen.io/Ryuh/pen/oLNvRj

Comment: why do you want to make it using a single div. It would be much easier and convenient, if instead of different backgrounds, you keep separate divs, with those backgrounds and animate those.

Comment: http://codepen.io/mblase75/pen/wWvvjY -- the only real change I had to make was to add `html,body { height: 100%; }` to the CSS, because otherwise the  `#slideit` has no content to give it height.

Comment: It didin't do it, the images aren't full screen. I don't know what I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Inside `setInterval`, we just need to overwrite `background-image` instead of `background` itself. This should fix the full screen issue.

```
image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images [i++] +')');
```

Comment: Actually I tried the code hosted on codepen and it works as expected. I don't see the first image looping issue. Is it browser specific issue ? May be we can try doing `i++` next to the current line. I believe the concatenation and increment operator will not interfere with each other.